# Adding another style to an OpenStreetMap server using Mapnik, PostGIS, etc

Tags: openstreetmap, tilemill, mapnik

I have created an OpenStreetMap server using the guide *[Manually building a tile server (12.04)](http://switch2osm.org/serving-tiles/manually-building-a-tile-server-12-04/)*. It's very good and works like a charm. I have also been able to add a new theme using TileMill and osm-bright.

However, I now want to be able to switch between two themes, osm-bright and my own osm-night. Is this an Apache question or is there a way to modify Mapnik to be able to get a parameter from, for example, openlayers to switch between these two themes?

Comment: https://github.com/mapbox/osm-bright theme

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The style is invoked in renderd.conf with something like

```
XML=/home/jburgess/osm/svn.openstreetmap.org/applications/rendering/mapnik/osm-local.xml
```

So you can exchange that call to another xml file, or use two configuration files for renderd.

If it is pure mapnik, duplicate generate_tiles.py, and change `mapfile = "osm.xml"` to another style file.

In both cases, you should change the output folder too to avoid overwriting your original tiles.